# VSCode change key binding for cancel signal in terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

Not sure if it's called the "cancel signal" but I'm talking about <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> when you want to stop something running. I actually want `Terminal: Copy Selection` to be <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, and this I can change in `Keyboard Shortcuts`. But then I have no way of changing the cancel signal to what I want, which is: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. That's because I can't seem to find that key binding.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is only valid for shells, which for VSCOde only run in terminal panes. The other key bindings you speak of apply to the VSCode IDE in general, not to any shell running in a terminal pane that might exist.

When a terminal pane has focus you should find that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> works as usual. I do not think that key binding is reassignable since it is built into the shell running in the terminal pane.

However, VSCode provides the ability to kill the active terminal, or to relaunch it. Maybe you would like to assign hotkeys to those actions?

BTW, you can set the behavior for terminal panes, so they copy to clipboard whenever text is selected. No keystroke required. You can enable that feature by editing `settings.json` and adding this line:

```
    "terminal.integrated.copyOnSelection": true,
```

Comment: Right, so my normal Ubuntu terminal has `$SHELL = /usr/bin/zsh`. And under the preferences there I changed "copy" to be Ctrl+C, and then the "cancel" command (which I can't actually change via preferences) automatically changed to Ctrl+Shift+C. In the VSCode terminal I still have `$SHELL = /usr/bin/zsh` but none of the previously mentioned changes get forwarded to it. So I went ahead and changed the "copy" key binding in VSCode hoping that I'd get lucky again. No cigar

Comment: VSCode does not forward keystrokes to terminals unless they have focus

Comment: Right, not sure if I'm using wrong terms here, but I'm definitely focussed on the terminal pane in all contexts I've discussed so far

Comment: I just added the suggestion in my answer about killing or relaunching the active terminal.

Comment: My answer's latest change is to mention `terminal.integrated.copyOnSelection`, which might be your best option. I use this myself.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up finding out I could use `stty intr ^k` to at least change it to k instead of c. Problem now is that vscode thinks I've started a chord. Ah! got it. `stty intr ^q` will work. It will take some getting used to it, but it's done most of what I need

Comment: And I appreciate your copyOnSelection tip, but I've worked with that before and it personally drives me nuts

Answer (score 0):

You can send a control sequence to the terminal, see [send text to a terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_send-text-from-a-keybinding) like this:

```
 {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+c",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
        "text": "\u0003\u000D"   // Ctrl+C
    },
    // "when": "terminalFocus && !terminalTextSelected"
  },
```

Use the `when` clause if you want it available only when the terminal has focus and with or without a selection.

`\u003` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> see

> /** End of Text (Caret = ^C) */
> export const ETX = '\x03';

from [escape sequences](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/blob/0e45909c7e79c83452493d2cd46d99c0a0bb585f/src/common/data/EscapeSequences.ts)

and `\u000D` is a return from the same source.

---

And then your other code to set Ctrl+C to copy terminal text:

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+c",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.copySelection",
        "when": "terminalFocus && terminalProcessSupported && terminalTextSelected && terminalTextSelected"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+c",
        "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.copySelection",
        "when": "terminalFocus && terminalProcessSupported && terminalTextSelected && terminalTextSelected"
    }
```

Demo already running a `serve` task :

[image: sendSequence demo of killing a task]